# Building dictionary from list using for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have multiple format files in a directory. I am trying to build a list or dictionary to group similar formatted (extension) files in python using for loop, but somehow it is not working.

Here is my sample code:

```
extension = ['pdf','xlsx','doc']

file_name_path=[]
file_dict ={}
for i in range(len(extension)):
    for file_name in filelst:
        if os.path.splitext(file_name)[-1] == extension[i]:
            file_name_path.append(file_name)
            file_dict[str(extension[i])]= file_name_path


file_name_path   
file_dict
```

where filelst is a list having all file names for example like

```
filelst = 
['PD_CFS_PLL_OnMonSummary_2017Q2.xlsx',
 'PD_Detailed_OMR_PLL_Lines_2017Q2.xlsx',
 'PD_Detailed_OMR_PLL_Loans_2017Q2.xlsx',
 'regexp-tip-sheet.pdf',
 'SAS statistical-business-analyst certification .pdf']
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"not working"*? It doesn't actually print or output anything, if that's what you mean.

Comment: wheres your `i`?

Comment: also, have a look at the `endswith` builtin method

Comment: my bad. i just edited the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative method to get dictionary with extensions as keys

```
extension = ['.pdf','.xlsx','.doc']
filelist = ['one.pdf','two.pdf','three.doc','four.xlsx'] #just for example
d = dict()
for i in extension:
    d[i] = [j for j in filelist if os.path.splitext(j)[-1].lower()==i]
print(d)
```

output:

```
{'.doc': ['three.doc'], '.xlsx': ['four.xlsx'], '.pdf': ['one.pdf', 'two.pdf']}
```

Note that I used dots in extension list as `os.path.splitext` return list with last element being `'.extension'`. `.lower()` is used to made this solution case-insensitive, strings in `extension` list have to contain lowercase characters only.

Comment: I like your method. Thanks it worked. I am new to Python and if possible could you please explain me the logic after for loop in line before print statement.

Comment: It is known as list comprehension, for explanation see this tutorial: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the dictionaries value each time the same key is seen.

Instead, use a list as the value and append.  This is what `defaultdict` is for.

from collections import defaultdict

```
extension = ['pdf','xlsx','doc']

file_dict = defaultdict(list)

for file_name in filelst:
    ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)[-1].lower()
    if ext in extension:
        file_dict[ext].append(file_name)
```